# EF edmx model migration does not work

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

i am designing the Entity Framework data model (EF designer from database). The problem is that when i change the .edmx model by clicking "Generate database from existing model" the data that stores in database removes. So how can i migrate data when i want to change database structure? I have tried to add migration in package manager console, but i have got an error:"Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRGFZ.png)

Comment: cod first technique is used when you generate database from code ,what do you mean by "code first from existing database"?

Comment: Sorry, i just confused. When i add EF data model i choose "EF Disigner from database in Entity Data Model Wizard".

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please read carefully the code first technique creating database so if you are using the same connection string the database will obviously lost.Please read this documentation carefully https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: The are not any error. The problem is that when i for example wanna change one of my tables, let it be ExprTypeDir, for instance i want to add new column, in EF designer i click add new --> scalar property. Then i click "Generete database from model" and my database structure changes, but the data that stored in tables before removes. So how can i migrate all my data when i change the data model structure? Maybe i use wrong way to do it?